# Increase counter value when object.posistion.x changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that increases the value of a counter only if `object.posistion.x` changes. The problem is when the `object.position.y` changes, it also increases the counter value ... how to fix it ?

Here's my script:

```
void Start () {
    X = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("counter").transform.position.x;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    X1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("counter").transform.position.x

    if (X!=X1)
    {
        counter++;
        result = counter;
    }

}
```

Comment: you shouldnt "find" the object each update, cache the result in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althrough your question is a little bit unclear, I think this is what you are looking for (increasing the counter only when `X` changes and `Y` is stable):

```
void Start () 
{
    var pos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("counter").transform.position;

    X = pos.x;
    Y = pos.y;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    var pos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("counter").transform.position;

    if ((X != pos.x) && (Y == pos.y))
        result = ++counter;
}
```

By the way, don't abuse the `FindGameObjectWithTag`. Retrieve it only once and store it into a variable. This could represent a huge performance hit.

Comment: i did it , but the condition always false .. :/

Comment: Well, that means your object is not moving only horizontally... is that what you see?

Comment: Even when moved it Manually using the inspector the counter's value still 0

Comment: thank u ,, it worked fine ..
also i enhanced the performance as u mentioned.